# Simple form with phpmailer v6

Tags: forms, phpmailer, contact-form

I need a little help on my contact form with phpmailer v6.
My question id how do I pass the contact form data to my esender.php ?
Your help will be more than appreciate.

*Please note my esender.php work well. Now I need just to grab the information from the form.

This is my simple bootstrap4 contact form:

```
<form method="POST" action="esender.php">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" id="name" name="name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="WebSite" id="website" name="website">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FormControlSelect">Tell me about your project</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="project" name="project">
                      <option selected value="Please select one">Please select one</option>
                      <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
                      <option value="e-Commerce">e-Commerce</option>
                      <option value="OnSite">OnSite SEO</option>
                      <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                      <option value="Internet Hosting">Internet Hosting</option>
                      <option value="CyberSecurity">CyberSecurity</option>
                      <option value="Encrypted Email">Encrypted Email</option>
                      <option value="Technical Support">Technical Support</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FormTextarea">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="themessage" rows="3" name="themessage"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary submit" type="submit">Submit form</button>
                </form>
```

And this is my esender.php

```
    <?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // Mail server configuration
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
    $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    // Recipients
    $mail->SetFrom('email@gmail.com', 'My Name');
    $mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', 'My Name');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('email@outlook.com', 'Some Name');

    // Content
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Test is Test Email';
    //$mail->Body = 'Send HTML Email using SMTP in PHP, This is a test email I’m sending using SMTP mail server with PHPMailer.';

    $mail->Body = <<<EOT
    First Name: {$_POST['firstname']}
    Name: {$_POST['name']}
    Email: {$_POST['email']}
    Website: {$_POST['website']}
    Project: {$_POST['project']}
    Message: {$_POST['themessage']}
    EOT;

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent!';

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [the example contact form provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer use the POST method to get the parameters.

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
?>
```

And so on. Now you will be able to use the variables in your PHP mailer.